# Problems installing composer on 1and1 shared hosting

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I t's my first time to a laravel web application on 1and1. For my dependances i need composer but i can't install it.
This is what i made. 
    I create the following folders bin/composer 
    then i install composer`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php7.1`

Result: `X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.12
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.6.2) successfully installed to: /homepages/11/d715566175/htdocs/bin/composer/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

`When i use`php composer.phar`i got these errors:`
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in **/homepages/11/d715566175/htdocs/bin/composer/composer.phar** on line **95**

`Even php -v returns`4.4.9`
Need your helps 
Thanks

Comment: Try to upgrade php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your default PHP which you call with `php` refers to an old version of PHP . Try `php7.1 composer.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
/usr/bin/php7.4-cli composer.phar -v
```